# How to implement conditional operator in hbs for ember app

Tags: ember.js

I have implemented a check on hbs for styling a page

I have two style class

```
open-gl
open-tx
```

with below code , I can apply a style to a div tag

`{{unless openGLpresent 'open-gl'}}`

but how to implement a else function here

it is like 
`{{unless openGLpresent 'open-gl' else 'open-tx'}}`

thanks , i tried it but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the `unless` conditionals is slightly malformed. We don't need to specify the `else` clause in an `if` or `unless` helper, just the two arguments would be enough. The first argument will be returned when the specified condition satisfy and if not, the second argument will be returned.

So your `unless` conditional would be:

```html
{{unless openGLpresent 'open-gl' 'open-tx'}}
```

however, this can be translated to `if` conditional for easy readability:

```html
{{if openGLpresent 'open-tx' 'open-gl'}}
```

For more details, refer the **Inline form** section of [this API doc.](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.15/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/if?anchor=if)